# Gitlab runner fails to authenticate with credentials from ~/.docker/config.json

Tags: git, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to run a project from gitlab CI/CD and I'm getting the following error:

```
  on Gitlab-runner-1 M--MHsVp
Using Docker executor with image registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cluster-integration/auto-build-image/master:stable ...
Starting service docker:stable-dind ...
Authenticating with credentials from /home/Pq515devops/.docker/config.json
Pulling docker image docker:stable-dind ...
Using docker image sha256:eaed9efc02d231a28b0f7725551a71459a7763e83bcda5464db66ec4684a1639 for docker:stable-dind ...
Waiting for services to be up and running...

*** WARNING: Service runner-M--MHsVp-project-3187-concurrent-0-docker-0 probably didn't start properly.

Health check error:
ContainerStart: Error response from daemon: Cannot link to a non running container: /runner-M--MHsVp-project-3187-concurrent-0-docker-0 AS /runner-M--MHsVp-project-3187-concurrent-0-docker-0-wait-for-service/service (executor_docker.go:1254:0s)

Service container logs:
2019-11-14T12:48:10.698686600Z mount: permission denied (are you root?)
2019-11-14T12:48:10.700536600Z Could not mount /sys/kernel/security.
2019-11-14T12:48:10.700550600Z AppArmor detection and --privileged mode might break.
2019-11-14T12:48:10.703434000Z mount: permission denied (are you root?)

*********

Pulling docker image registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cluster-integration/auto-build-image/master:stable ...
Using docker image sha256:c114dffc16419102b42958970133bc5950c85961747ba2ed9d37741457d829df for registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cluster-integration/auto-build-image/master:stable ...
Authenticating with credentials from /home/Pq515devops/.docker/config.json
Running on runner-M--MHsVp-project-3187-concurrent-0 via Gitlab-runner-1...
Authenticating with credentials from /home/Pq515devops/.docker/config.json
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/bsmchstudents/whitesmokerph36/.git/
Created fresh repository.
remote: You are not allowed to download code from this project.
fatal: unable to access 'http://gitlab-ci-token:[MASKED]@gitlab.it.bsmch.net/bsmchstudents/whitesmokerph36.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
Authenticating with credentials from /home/Pq515devops/.docker/config.json
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I tried running other project and they all end with the `ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1` error.
I tried looking online for a solution and it seemed like there isn't one cause for this error, and I tried some stuff others found helpful though nothing changed, for example one solution I saw was adding `unset cd` to ./bashrc which didn't change anything.
Gitlab-runner and docker are both installed on the gitlab runner server (Ubuntu 18.04).
I have 3 shared runners and I registered a runner for each project I have on gitlab using the `gitlab-runner register` command.
Before clicking "Retry" in Gitlab I'm running `gitlab-runner run` command and it checks for jobs from all the runners and once it finds it loads it and then after some time sends this: `WARNING: Job failed: exit code 1                    duration=13.6350221s job=19551 project=3187 runner=M--MHsVp
WARNING: Failed to process runner                   builds=0 error=exit code 1 executor=docker runner=M--MHsVp`.

I thought it might be related to `/home/Pq515devops/.docker/config.json` file:

```
{
        "auths": {
                "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
                        "auth": "*****"
                }
        },
        "HttpHeaders": {
                "User-Agent": "Docker-Client/18.09.7 (linux)"
        },
        "proxies": {
                "default": {
                        "httpProxy": "http://10.0.0.10.80",
                        "httpsProxy": "http://10.0.0.10:80"
                }
        }
}
```

Also some time ago the same error was given and adding the proxies section fixed it, until now that the same error returned.

Anyone has a recommendation for a fix for this or knows something about it?

Comment: `You are not allowed to download code from this project` : are you member of the gitlab project with sufficient rights ?

Comment: @NicolasPepinster Yes, admin member.

Answer (score 0):

This might be because the runner with executor docker doesn't use the ~/­.bashrc and doesn't set the variables in there.
You have to set the variables in your Dockerfile and rebuild your image.

To set variables, do:

> ENV VARIABLE

where VARIABLE is the thing you export in the ~/.bashrc.

If this does not work maybe try [this](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/82).